# Save dynamicly named Images from HTTPBasicAuthHander Authenticated page

Tags: python, html, image, wildcard, urllib

I am wanting to open a webpage of a internal webpage for a reporting tool called statseeker, that stores images that are generated from a report ran when a URL is opened. So far I am at this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2


urlauth = 'http://statseeker/cgi/nim-report-lastn-drilldown?mode=ping&tz=America/Chicago&last_n=24h&device=jc-2090-1'
realm = 'statseeker'
username = 'admin'
password = '*******'
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm, urlauth, username, password)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
data = opener.open(urlauth).read()
print data
```

This code is successful in accessing the web page and generating graphs as .PNG images twoards the end of the page, as output is listed below:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
>>>
>>> urlauth = 'http://statseeker/cgi/nim-report-lastn-drilldown?mode=ping&tz=Ame
rica/Chicago&last_n=24h&device=jc-2090-1'
>>> realm = 'statseeker'
>>> username = 'admin'
>>> password = '******'
>>> auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
>>> auth_handler.add_password(realm, urlauth, username, password)
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
>>> data = opener.open(urlauth).read()
>>> print data
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/st
rict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Ping Statistics - Last 24 Hours</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base.css">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/unsupported_browser.html">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/nim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<p class="p0">
<div align="center">
<table class="r_twb">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
         <table class="r_hdr" width="99%"><tbody>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="2" class="leftlogo">
                  <img class="ss_logo2" src="/img/ss_logo_inverse_small.png">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <div class="r_hdr_title">Ping Statistics - Last 24 Hours</div>

               </td>
               <td nowrap class="rightlogo">
                  <span   class="top_right" id="tog_refresh" title="start/pause
refresh" onclick="toggle_refresh(this)">
                     Refresh: <span id="refresh_id" >60</span>
                     <script type="text/javascript">toggle_refresh()</script>
                  </span>

                  <span class="top_right" onclick="schedule();">
                     <img src="/img/mail.png"
                          id="schedimg"
                          title="Email this Report"
                          onmouseover="this.src='/img/mail_light.png'"
                          onmouseout="this.src='/img/mail.png'">
                  </span>
                  <span class="top_right" onclick="create_pdf();">
                     <img src="/img/file_pdf.png"
                          id="pdfimg"
                          title="Create PDF"
                          onmouseover="this.src='/img/file_pdf_bright.png'"
                          onmouseout="this.src='/img/file_pdf.png'">
                  </span>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2">
                  <table class="r_hdr"><tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center;" id="td_tzselect">&nbsp;
<select id="tz" name="tz" onchange="change_tz(this.options[this.selectedIndex].v
alue); return false;">
                <option value="America/Chicago" selected>America/Chicago
</select>


                        </td>
                        <td nowrap style="text-align:right;" id="timedisplay">
                           Sun 13 Jul 2014, 19:09
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody></table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody></table>
      </td>
   </tr> <tr class="r_summary"><td class="r_d9" colspan="5"><select id="lastn" n
ame="lastn" onchange="change_lastn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); retu
rn false;"> <option value="12h">Last 12 Hours <option value="24h" selected>Last
24 Hours <option value="48h">Last 48 Hours <option value="7d">Last 7 Days <optio
n value="30d">Last 30 Days <option value="60d">Last 60 Days <option value="90d">
Last 90 Days <option value="lastmonth">Last Month <option value="thismonth">This
 Month <option value="lastyear">Last Year <option value="thisyear">This Year</se
lect></td></tr>

 <tr class="r_col_hdr">
  <td valign="top"></td>
  <td valign="top">Minimum</td>
  <td valign="top">Maximum</td>
  <td valign="top">Average</td>
  <td valign="top">Total</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row0">
  <td class="r_d0l">Delay (ms)</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">53</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">106</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">54</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">-</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row1">
  <td class="r_d0l">Duplicate Responses</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row0">
  <td class="r_d0l">Lost 1</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">1</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row1">
  <td class="r_d0l">Lost 2</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row0">
  <td class="r_d0l">Lost 3</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="alt_row1">
  <td class="r_d0l">Lost 4</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
  <td class="r_d0r">0</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</p>
<p class="p10">
<img class="graph" src="/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.rtt.24h.1405296595.png">
</p>
<p class="p10">
<img class="graph" src="/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.lost.24h.1405296595.png">
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how to go about saving those images. The file name at the end changes every second.

I would like to be able to save any file on the page that I choose their name up to the wildcard part.

so something with the premise of:

1. save any image with this name `/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.rtt.24h.1%%%%%%%%.png` in that web page.
2. and `save` it in this new file location that choose, with the name I choose.
3. Maybe save everything in the `image class=graph` section?

**Any Ideas?**

Concerns:

1. Images will always be name the same type of thing up until the last section of the url. This is generated by the reporting software and can not be changed. So every file will appear the same up to that:

/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.rtt.24h.%%%%%%%%%.png
/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.lost.24h.%%%%%%%%%.png

Once that is figured out all I don't have much left other then making pretty html website to display these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lxml` or `BeutifulSoup` to parse that page and get easy access to HTML tags on page.

I can't test it but it could be something like this.

`data` = your HTML string

```
import lxml, lxml.html

html = lxml.html.fromstring( data )

imgs = html.cssselect('img.graph')

for x in imgs:
   print 'http://statseeker%s' % ( x.attrib['src'] )
```

This should print urls to files.

Now you could use your code to get this files (one by one) and then save new `data` in local files.

---

**EDIT:**

```
# get all urls

imgs_urls = []

for x in imgs:
   imgs_urls.append( 'http://statseeker%s' % (x.attrib['src']) )

# print all urls

for url in imgs_urls:
    print url
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after I installed cssselect. I am most pleased as it listed the complete url of them.

'>>>
>>> html = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
>>> imgs = html.cssselect('img.graph')
>>> for x in imgs:
...    print 'http://statseeker%s' % (x.attrib['src'])
...
http://statseeker/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.rtt.24h.1405308316.png
http://statseeker/graphs/ping.jc-2090-1.lost.24h.1405308316.png
>>>
>>>
>>>'

Comment: So to come back to this. It will only work for the first image on the page. If there are multiple images how would I go about making it work ? 

I already put the first one into a variable like so:

y = 'http://statseeker%s' % ( x.attrib['src'] )

How would I do it for multiple images?

Comment: You can keep urls on the list - and then you can print them (one by one) or use them to download - see example in answer.